# Run proxy server on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, networking, networkextension

For an enterprise application I want to run a proxy server continuously locally on iOS. Steps I have taken so far:

1. Use NEPacketTunnelProvider to create a tunnel
2. Tunnel the traffic to 127.0.0.1:8080
3. Start Proxy Server from the network extension (this works!)

Step 3 works, however, it seems like after starting up it stops working. I could imagine this having to do something with not being able to run such a process continuously. Does anyone have an idea or a pointer?

Comment: I doubt that running a usable proxy server on iOS is possible, due to security restrictions. Maybe https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/86110 can give some insights.

Comment: Hi, can you help me one thing in which class you are running the server, is it the same subclass of NEPacketTunnelProvider or will there any other extension?, I tried to create a sever inside NEPacketTunnelProvider subclass but the server isnt running. Thanks!

Comment: any luck guys as I am also facing this issue